# Markov Chain - transition matrix

Tags: probability

could you help me with this question concerning Markov chains? I can't even seem to construct a transition matrix.

A fish-lover keeps three fish in three aquaria;initially there are two pikes and one trout. Each day, independently of other days, the fish-lover looks at a randomly chosen aquarium and either doesn't do anything (with probability 2/3), or changes the fish in that aquarium to a fish of the second species (with probability 1/3).
a) Calculate the probability that after two days all three fish in the aquaria will be of the same species.
b) What is the average number of days until all three fish in the aquaria will be of the same species?
c) Approximate the probability that after two years all three fish in the aquaria will be of the same species, with the use of the Ergodic theorem.

Could anybody help me?Please

Answer (score 0):

The first that comes to my mind is using a two-state markov chain: There can be 2 (state A) or 3 (state B) fish of the same species and we begin in the state with 2 (state A). Now:

- There is only one way in which we can move from A to B: the fish-lover picks the aquaria of the trout and changes it by a pike which will happen with probability $1/9$.
- The probability of going from state B to state A is $1/3$.

With this probabilities you can build your transition matrix. To answer question a) you can use the transition matrix or use brute force: The probability of being in state B after two days is: $P(A \rightarrow B\rightarrow B)+P(A\rightarrow A\rightarrow B)=\frac{1}{9}\frac{2}{3}+\frac{8}{9}\frac{1}{9}=\frac{14}{81}=0.173$

For the others you will need to use a power of the transition matrix which can be calculated using a decomposition or with a computer.

Comment: Thank you, but could you explain how you would get from state A to A? I see that it's enough to sum the row to 1 but I can't explain how 8/9 would be there. Don't we have 2 fish that are the same, so pike pike trout AND trout trout and pike? Or should we just stick to the given info that we have pike pike trout? Because I thought that it is only relevant in point a). And that in the matrix we should consider every option. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: In the way i think of it, if one of the two pikes is changed by a trout we would remain in state A. Maybe there are other ways to model this situation but as the questions are about the probability of being all of the same species i think it is good to treat this two situations as part of the same state (A)

Comment: By the way, it does not matter if you initially have 2 trouts or 2 pikes. Both cases imply that you start in state A and transition probabilities remain the same.